# Error about creating PDF manual when I did the R CMD Check

Tags: r, latex, r-package, pdflatex

Here is the error message I met:

- checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING

LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.

LaTeX errors found:

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.

- checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR

Any thoughts to solve? Thank you so much!

Comment: Two possible approaches: use `$\alpha$` instead of `α` or switch to an unicode engine like lualatex or xelatex

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I double-checked it. I am sure that I already revised α  to $\alpha$. May i know how to switch to lualatex or xelatex?